# Seeking free vector data on paved roads in Africa?

Tags: data, road, africa, infrastructure

I have recently come across vector road data from the Africa Infrastructure Knowledge Program (http://www.infrastructureafrica.org/documents/list/roads). I found these data helpful for three reasons:

1. They are freely available
2. They cover most sub-saharan countries
3. Information on road surface (e.g. paved/unpaved, asphalt/gravel/earth) is available for all surveyed countries

Do these data have serious limitations, I should be aware of?

And if yes, could you recommend better data, which allow a comprehensive assessment of paved roads in Africa?

Comment: I have never worked with this dataset, but the source looks more than credible. I don't think you'll find something better elsewhere.

Comment: http://download.geofabrik.de/africa.html has more detailed roads (from gps traces) Africa Infrastructure Knowledge Program is at a small scale of capture. (osm is shapefile ready to load into a gis like qgis)